# Exporting PDF with Hyperlinked Attributes from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, hyperlink, geospatial-pdf

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and would like to export a map to a pdf, preserving feature's attributes. I would like to be able to identify, for example, a point feature from the map on pdf with its underlying features (essentially hyperlink to a document or URL). I know one can export to such a pdf in ArcMap, with an advanced option of exporting features with attributes. I use Adobe Acrobat Pro v.10, and cannot seem to be able to find a way to bring these attributes up.

Is this possible?

Comment: has this been answered? if so, can you close it off? else, can you add content as to what needs clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to explore the GEOPDF function within ArcGIS. You can access the functionality by Selecting File>Export then select "PDF" as your Save As Type. Click the Advanced Tab and select "Export PDF Layers and Feature Attributes". See Image below for presets.

In order to access the content in the PDF: First you will need to open the area that the attribute data will display in. In order to do that click the "Page Thumbnails" icon on the left side of the window (see image two below).  Then you will need to make use of the 'identify' tool To do so: Select Edit>Analysis>Object Data Tool. Click on the feature you would like information about by using the cross hairs of the object data tool. The tabular information will populate in the Thumbnail window (see image 3 below).

In order to access the Hyperlink you would have a field that is populated as a [hyperlink](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000004000000). Then have the users select the link in the Model Tree window of Adobe. For example, in the Identify Tool Image, you can replace Surrey Street with a hyperlink and then it will become an active directory link.

**Caveat - this tool is very restrictive if you have a lot of content it will most likely crash every time. I would say a good best practice is to reduce the content to the minimum requirements. But fiddle with it as it may react differently on your machine.

Export Image

[image]

Thumbnail Image
[image: ImageTwo]

Identify Tool
[image: Image3]

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer. Not sure if this is because of my Adobe version (10.0), but I cannot see object data identify tool. Which version of Adobe do you use? I can double-click on the field URL, and this opens up window with URL value, but does not navigate to the actual address. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey I am on Adobe Reader 11.0.09. but have had luck in the past with all other versions. How did you try to access the object data tool?

Comment: @MDHALD - In the newer versions of Adobe Reader, particularly 10+, you can access the Object Data tool by right clicking on the map itself and it is the last option in the drop down menu.