# Add Hyperlink to PDF of map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pdf, hyperlink

I know there isn't a way to export a map from ArcMap to PDF and keep the hyperlinks, but is there a way to add hyperlinks to the map in Adobe Acrobat? I have a simple map of a few states and I am wanting each state to link to a webpage. I know how to get to seeing the attributes in Adobe Acrobat, but can't figure out if I can add a hyperlink there.

I think this is different to [Exporting PDF with Hyperlinked Attributes from ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115505) which instead explains how you would have to go through the model tree to find the link. I am asking how to create a link on the states on the pdf, so that you wouldn't have to search through the pdf to find the links.

Answer (score 2):

If your features have labels you can highlight them in Acrobat using the text cursor, right click, choose "create link", choose to open in a web page, provide url.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can correct me if i'm wrong but I don't think there is a way to do that in ArcMap.

You can add hyperlinks in pdf's using acrobat pro. Or alternatively we use GeoPDf's at work that do that although i believe that it is also a paid application.